# div sort not working when div generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of divs with the properties shown by particular attributes (gender, level, name etc) using the following script:

html:

```
<div id="sortThis" class="col-xs-12 alert-container">
    <div id="1" class="container-element sortable box box-blue" data-gender="1" data-level="4" data-name="AAA">   <h3>AAA</h3><div class="panel-body">AAA is resp</div>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="container-element sortable box box-pink" data-gender="2" data-level="3" data-name="DDD"><h3>DDD</h3><div class="panel-body">DDD is a s</div>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="container-element sortable box box-blue" data-gender="1" data-level="2" data-name="FFF"><h3>FFF</h3><div class="panel-body">FFF has mad</div>
    </div>
    <div id="4" class="container-element sortable box box-pink" data-gender="2" data-level="4" data-name="CCC"><h3>CCC</h3><div class="panel-body">CCC has ma</div>
    </div>
    <div id="5" class="container-element sortable box box-pink" data-gender="2" data-level="2" data-name=EEE><h3>EEE</h3><div class="panel-body">EEE is a f</div>
    </div>
    <div id="6" class="container-element sortable box box-blue" data-gender="1" data-level="3" data-name="BBB"><h3>BBB</h3><div class="panel-body">BBB is an ou</div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="sLevel" class="LbtnSort">Sort by Level</button><br/>
<button id="sGender" class="GbtnSort">Sort by Gender</button><br/>
```

js:

```
var LdivList = $(".box");
LdivList.sort(function(a, b){ 
return $(a).data("level")-$(b).data("level")
});

var GdivList = $(".box");
GdivList.sort(function(a, b){ 
return $(a).data("gender")-$(b).data("gender")
});


/* sort on button click */
$("button.LbtnSort").click(function() {
$("#sortThis").html(LdivList);
});

/* sort on button click */
$("button.GbtnSort").click(function() {
$("#sortThis").html(GdivList);
});
```

when the .sortable divs are static, the sort works fine, as this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mike_ie/tc5dc/1161/) shows, however if the contents of the #sortable div (i.e. .sortable divs) are dynamically generated (in this case as the result of a form submit), when the sort button is pressed, the entire contents of the #sortable div disappears, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

edit: The code for dynamic generation of the list is as follows - effectively it's an AXAX form submit that pulls data from a sorted list of items and outputs them.

```
    $('#formStep2').submit(function(event) {
    // get the form data
    var studentArray = [];

    $(".listbox li").each(function() {
        studentArray.push({
            'name': ($(this).text()),
            'gender': ($(this).closest('ol').attr('id')).substr(0, 1),
            'level': ($(this).closest('ol').attr('id')).substr(2, 3),
            'topic': ($('input[name=topic]').val())
        })
    });
    var studentString = JSON.stringify(studentArray);
    console.log(studentString);
    var formData = {
        'students': studentString,
    };
    // process the form
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url: 'process_step2.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data: formData, // our data object
            dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode: true
        })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            if (!data.success) {
                // error handling to go here.....

            } else {
                $('.alert-container').empty();
                var obj = JSON.parse(data.message);

                //sort the array alphabetically by name (default status)
                var test = obj.sort(function(a,b){
                    var lccomp = a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());
                    return lccomp ? lccomp : a.name > b.name ? 1 : a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0;
                });

                console.log(test);

                var i=0;
                test.forEach(function(st) {
                    console.log(st['name']);
                    var gen = (st['gender'] == 1) ? "blue" : (st['gender'] == 2) ? "pink" : NULL;
                    $('.alert-container').append('<div id="' + (i+1) + '" class="container-element sortable box box-' + gen + '" data-gender="' + st['gender'] + '" data-level="' + st['level'] + '" data-name="' + st['name'] + '"><h3>' + st['name'] + '</h3><div class="panel-body"><div class="col-xs-9"><i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-3x fa-pull-left fa-' + gen + '" aria-hidden=:true"></i>' + st['comment'] + '</div></div></div>');
                    i++;
                });
                // jump to the next tab
                var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
                $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
                nextTab($active);
            }
        })
        // using the fail promise callback
        .fail(function(data) {
            // show any errors
            // best to remove for production
            console.log(data);
        });
    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Show your code for dynamic generation?

Comment: You are probably inserting elements after you have created the LdivList and GdivList variables, so they will not match anything because nothing is there yet. Would be my guess.

Comment: code for dynamic generation appended to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining LdivList and GdivList inline with your code so they are defined on DOM ready. You have to wrap the definition of those inside a function and call it on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button.LbtnSort").click(function() {
  $("#sortThis").html(GenerateLdivList);
  });

  /* sort on button click */
  $("button.GbtnSort").click(function() {
  $("#sortThis").html(GenerateGdivList());
  });
});


function GenerateLdivList(){
  var LdivList = $(".box");
  LdivList.sort(function(a, b){ 
  return $(a).data("level")-$(b).data("level")
  });
}

function GenerateGdivList(){
  var GdivList = $(".box");
  GdivList.sort(function(a, b){ 
  return $(a).data("gender")-$(b).data("gender")
  });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to sort gender and level in a one function?

Answer (score 0):

As @theduke said, the lists are probably empty at the time you sort them. Here's a simple change that will read and sort the lists when you click the buttons instead. (Not tested.)

```
var LdivList = function () {
  return $(".box").sort(function(a, b){ 
    return $(a).data("level")-$(b).data("level")
  });
};

var GdivList = function () {
  return $(".box").sort(function(a, b){ 
    return $(a).data("gender")-$(b).data("gender")
  });
};


/* sort on button click */
$("button.LbtnSort").click(function() {
  $("#sortThis").html(LdivList());
});

/* sort on button click */
$("button.GbtnSort").click(function() {
  $("#sortThis").html(GdivList());
});
```

Comment: Apologies for the slow replies - I live in a country with abysmally slow internet. As one person mentioned, I needed to call my functions on click rather than on load, as both solutions above remedied. Thank you all once again for your patience and help.